# Поиск второго по величине элемента в массиве на Ruby

Tags: массивы, ruby

```
def pre_max(array)
i=0
max_el = array[0]
pre_max_el = -Float::INFINITY
  (1..array.length).map do |i|
    if max_el < i
      pre_max_el = max_el
      max_el = i
    end
  end
  if pre_max_el == -Float::INFINITY
    puts 'nil'
  else 
      puts pre_max_el
  end
end
    pre_max([3,1,4,32,6,8])
```

Результат = индекс последнего элемента массива.
Подскажите где ошибка?

Comment: А если сделать так: `array.sort[-2]`? Или вам важно написать именно алгоритм?

Comment: Именно алгоритм нужен)
Нельзя менять каким-либо образом массив, нельзя использовать другой массив.

Answer (score 1):

1. Методы не должны ничего печатать -- они должны возвращать значение, а решение о печати принимать следует "выше".
2. `'nil'` -- это не просто какая-то строка, которую печатают, когда вывести нечего, а специальный тип в Ruby.
3. Когда пишешь на Ruby, императивщину следует забыть, и в качестве параметра в каждой итерации `each` будет не индекс i, а сам i-ый элемент.
4. Чтобы не брать с потолка INFINITY, если в массиве не достаточно элементов, сразу вернем nil.

```rb
def pre_max array
  return if array.size < 2
  pre_max_el, max_el = array.take(2)
  pre_max_el, max_el = max_el, pre_max_el if pre_max_el > max_el
  array.drop(2).each do |el|
    pre_max_el = el if el > pre_max_el
    pre_max_el, max_el = max_el, pre_max_el if pre_max_el > max_el
  end
  pre_max_el
end
```

Comment: 2-е это понятно) по ТЗ нужен именно вывод - nil

Comment: @DenisOleshchenko, `return` без параметров возвращает `nil` из метода.